# Appending a global list to a global list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, backtracking

I have written following code for solving the [n-Queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) where we have to find all possible *legal* (non-attacking) placements of `n` queens in an `n*n` chessboard. The code uses the standard backtracking solution.

Here the method `n_queens` uses the helper method `solve_n_queens` which uses recursion. The outer method just initializes global lists `result` & `col_placement` and calls the helper method.

```
def n_queens(n):
    def solve_n_queens(row):
        if row == n: # all queens are legally placed
            result.append(list(col_placement))
            return
        for col in range(n):
            # check if new queen is either 1) in same column or 2) same diagonal with any previously placed queen
            if all(abs(col-c) not in (0, row-r) 
                   for r, c in enumerate(col_placement[:row])):
                col_placement[row] = col
                solve_n_queens(row+1)
    result, col_placement = [], [0] * n # result is empty initially; [0] * n means no queen is placed
    solve_n_queens(0)
    return result
```

This gives erroneous output for `n_queens(4)`

```
[[3, 1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2, 1]]
```

However it is not an algorithmic bug because just altering the 4th line `result.append(col_placement)` to **`result.append(list(col_placement))`** mysteriously gives the correct output

```
[[1, 3, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3, 1]]
```

What I don't grok is when `col_placement` is already a `list`, why do we need to call the `list` method?

Comment: This is a variant of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/364696); you're not using sequence multiplication, but the effect of appending the same name to the `list` multiple times without copying it or rebinding the name between appends is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that without using `list` you are appending a reference to the same and only list `col_placement` you are working with (as you can see the results are not only wrong, but they are also the same). Using `list` creates a new copy (a instant snapshot of `col_placement`) that will not be modified when `col_placement` does as you keep going through the rest of the program.

So essentially `list(col_placement)` is the same as `col_placement.copy()` or `col_placement[:]`.